# How can I make a "Variable Width Column Chart" on Power BI

Tags: charts, powerbi

I'm trying to create this chart on power BI but I don't know how to do it .
Can I have your help please

[image: THIS CHART]

AND those are the Data used to build the chart
[![DATA][2]][2]

Comment: It would help to know how the data looks like which will be used to make the chart. Without data it is difficult to understand which figure goes to which axis on the chart.

Comment: @Alok thanks for taking time to respond , I add the data to the question can you have a look please if this will help

Comment: Good question! This chart type is EXTREMELY popular in the energy business when it comes to showing the sequence in which power plants are bidding into the market (aka. "Merrit Order Curve")

Comment: @Peter Thank you very much I appreciate your contribution

Answer (score 1):

Power BI doesn't have this chart type by default. Your best option is to use a Python or R visual, e.g. like explained by RADACAD:

[image]

You can find a Python solution - that you could also use in Power BI - on StackOverflow her: [Altair bar chart with bars of variable width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59608560/altair-bar-chart-with-bars-of-variable-width)

[image]

Comment: Her's how to do this in Excel: https://www.extendoffice.com/excel/excel-charts/excel-variable-width-column-chart.html

Comment: Altair uses Vega under the hood. You can use Vega directly in Power BI using Deneb custom visual and that way you'll keep the interactivity for cross filtering etc.

Comment: @Peter Thanks a lot for the explanation , I will follow steps and use python as you said , thank you again